# Using an SSL certificate in multiple locations

Tags: ssl, ssl-certificate, certificate-authority, certificate

I have a website hosted in the UK and I also have an organisation in South Africa hosting my company application online for web access.

I want to implement SSL for both servers, as it requires login from different places and different people.

Is it possible to purchase just **one** SSL certificate for the company in the company name for one domain name and use it for both purposes? Will there be any conflict issuing the CSR?

Comment: Cross posted at http://security.stackexchange.com/questions/33680/using-ssl-certification-in-multiple-locations

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, this is possible.  You just need the private key from the server that the CSR was generated from.  Transfer that private key to both servers, along with the SSL cert and CA Bundle.

However, if you're using a sub-domain on the second server, then you'll either need a wildcard SSL or multiple SSL certificates.

Comment: Just to add to this - some CA's (eg Symantec) license their certificates per server and some have no limits on the number of servers a cert is installed on. Check the terms and conditions of your potential vendor prior to purchase to make sure it matches your intended usage.

Answer (score 2):

If both locations use the same URL there won't be any issue.  You could purchase a multi-SAN cert to use in both locations if you want to only use one certificate also.

SSL works by matching the URL you're visiting to the CN (or SANs) on the server, if they match (and the certificate is valid and not listed on the CA's CRL) then the client will be happy...otherwise you'll get a certificate error on the client's side.

Answer (score 1):

There will not be any conflict created of using your certificate with the two different server. Normally you can order one certificate for your domain and install to any number of physical server.Only the thing you needed is your private key. You can get the private key from your initial server where the CSR was created and use it on the desired server.

Or you will be having an option to export the certificate as a pfx file from the server where you have installed the certificate. through a open ssl command.

```
openssl pkcs12 -export -in my.crt -inkey my.key -certfile my.bundle -out my.pfx
```

To install the certificate on the server you can separate the private key from the pfx file and use it on your new server.

Extract the Certificate and Private Key into a separate PEM file

```
openssl pkcs12 -in yourP12File -nocerts -out privateKey.pem
```

In other way some certificate authority like comodo will provide the replacement of the issued certificate with free of cost. You can check with the CA for the replacement also.So you can simply recreate a new CSR on the new server and get it reissued. So you can install the reissued certificate without any trouble.